# Using word-break: break-word; on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, word-break

I have a div element that I am using for paragraphs of text. This is intended to be mobile-responsive, so I have been testing it with different browser/viewport sizes. I have the following code:

```css
.text {
  font-size: 18px;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  width: 200px;
  border: red solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Wordthatislongenoughtogetalineonitsown andawordthatfits fits</p>
```

When the window is resized, it looks fine on Chrome, with the w's going to a new line and then breaking. 
However, with Firefox, the words don't break at all, and the div element expands to include all the text, creating a scrollbar at the bottom of the page.

How can I get it so that the word breaks in Firefox? I have tried adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` but all it does is add ugly line breaks and doesn't even force the word break. I don't want to use `word-break: break-all;` because that would break every word, and I only want to break overflow words. `overflow-wrap: break-word;` also appeared to do nothing.

EDIT:
I am trying to get it to look like this, and this is how it looks on Chrome: [Chrome Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTwAv.png)

This is what it looks like on Firefox (not what I want): [Firefox Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6QpD.png)

This is what it looks like with `break-all`, which is not what I want either. Note how words are broken when they could move to the next line: [break-all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NaGo.png)

Comment: for FF, use `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` has different functionality though, with all words being broken

Comment: Actually, break-word is a value of word-wrap which was implemented in old IE(5.5->7), you might be here mistaking both rules :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/gg721773(v=expression.40).aspx which is back in the draft  as  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap  Best is to check out which you can apply to the rule you want to use, then pickup the ones that works as expected ;)

Comment: I've tried `overflow-wrap: break-word;` but nothing appears to happen, and the same goes for `word-wrap: break-word;`. My goal is to break the word if, and only if, it doesn't fit on a line by itself. The Chrome implementation that I linked above is exactly what I'm looking for. I get that `break-word` is nonstandard for WebKit browsers, but I'm looking for another way to get the same effect.

Comment: okay, i have made a snippet of your initial codes shared, maybe you can also add your few tries, so they can be reused in an answer and show live what happpens in the visitor's browser. I agree, FF behavior is weird at that point. overflow-wrap test https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POjbaW works fine in FF and Chrome, what version  os/browser do you use ?

Comment: That's weird, with `overflow-wrap` in the snippet it breaks properly in both Chrome and Firefox, but not on my site. Could it have to do with defining the width of the div? On my site I have the div width auto, but in the snippet it's defined.

Comment: no idea, CSS might be override by another rule else where or buggy with some other rules , (display, text-align, ..)?  i am indeed also confused for you :( (or  config ? autoprefixer/ prefixfree , ... ) in the way ?

Comment: According to the firefox console either `overflow-wrap` or `word-wrap` can be applied, but since they do the same thing that shouldn't be an issue. Also shouldn't be a config issue, as it occurs both locally and online.

Comment: For non-gibberish "words", but actual language instead, you might want to look into https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens And for content you are fully in control of, there's no reason not to be `&shy;` once in a while either.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest removing `word-break` at all, and just leave `overflow-wrap` (or `word-wrap`, if you want IE/Edge support) and it should be fine.

**Why?**

**Update**

It seems that the spec [has been updated](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#changes-2018-12-12) in Dec '18 to mention the `break-word` value as a deprecated one:

> For compatibility with legacy content, the word-break property also supports a deprecated break-word keyword. When specified, this has the same effect as word-break: normal and overflow-wrap: anywhere, regardless of the actual value of the overflow-wrap property.

**Old part of answer**

`word-break: break-word` seems to be a bug in Webkit-based browsers (or maybe a leftover from older css 3 drafts?), as `break-word` is a correct value only for `overflow-wrap` (or `word-wrap`, for older browsers (and Edge ;) ) property.

I've created a 
[comparison in js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0msyz4s/1/)

src:

[word-break spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#word-break-property)

[overflow-wrap / word-wrap spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-overflow-wrap)